# how to use variables in where clause of orientdb query using python

Tags: python, orientdb

code

```
import pyorient

# create connection 
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424) 

# open databse 
client.db_open( "testDB", "admin", "admin" ) 
requiredObj = client.command(" select out().question as qlist,out().seq as qseq,out().pattern as pattern,out().errormsg as errormsg from chat where app_cat='%s' and module='%s' and type='%s' and prob_cat='%s' ",(appCategory,module,type,problemCategory))

for data in requiredObj :
    print data
```

the above one is not working please suggest alternative way

Comment: Not working *how*? What happens? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this command

```
requiredObj = client.command("select from chat where name='%s'" % "chat 1");
```

or

```
requiredObj = client.command("select from chat where name='%s' and room='%s'" % ("chat 1","1"));
```

Hope it helps